# "expected statement" when running VBScript

Tags: vbscript

When I run my Script on the server I get the : expected statement

**My code**

```
if STATUS = "ERROR" then
    ext = LCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(sNewestFile))
    ' ZIP and RAR handler
    ' What should it do of the ext variable is zip or Rar?
    ' it is specified in the cases.
    Select Case ext
            Case "log", "txt"
                'Runs the tail.exe file to get the last 10 lines of text in the [sNewestFile] and insert them to the log file.
                'This will only be done IF there is a status = "ERROR"
                errorStr = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec( _ "tail -n 10 """ & sNewestFile & """" _ ).StdOut.ReadAll 
                objLogFile.writeline "" & vbCrLf
                objLogFile.writeline "Error Message Start" & vbCrLf
                objLogFile.writeline "" & errorStr & vbCrLf
                objLogFile.writeline "Error Message End" 
            Case "zip"
                objLogFile.writeline "" & vbCrLf
                objLogFile.writeline "The Date of the ZIP file is to old" & vbCrLf
            Case "rar"
                objLogFile.writeline "" & vbCrLf
                objLogFile.writeline "The Date of the RAR file is to old" & vbCrLf
    End Select 'Ends the Select Case ext
End If
```

The thing is that I keep getting somekind of error first it was *invalid character* I solved that by doing a prober if statement. Now its a *expected statement*.

I just cant seem to figurer out where, it goes wrong?

I've used the following for references:

- http://www.tizag.com/vbscriptTutorial/vbscriptelseif.php
- http://www.tizag.com/vbscriptTutorial/vbscriptselectcase.php
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604488/3430698
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32397175/3430698

Comment: Will this error occur if there is no `Case Else` in the select statement?

Answer (score 1):

Appearently the solution was to use :

```
errorStr = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec( _ 
      "tail -n 10 """ & sNewestFile & """" _ 
      ).StdOut.ReadAll
```

Instead of a 1 line :

```
errorStr = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec( _ "tail -n 10 """ & sNewestFile & """" _ ).StdOut.ReadAll
```

Why it is this way I have to clue of.

Comment: The `_` indicates to the parser that the line has been split and the code continues in the next line. If you want all the code in one line, remove the underscores.